# How to automatically assign students to cohort based on profile field?

Tags: moodle

I was wondering how/if it is possible to automatically assign a given student to a cohort based on the value of a field in their profile.

For example, I added a custom field for 'Library' with a dropdown list of various library names in the student profile.  If a student chooses 'Main St Library' I would like for them to be automatically placed in the 'Main St Library' cohort.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin available that does exactly that https://moodle.org/plugins/local_profilecohort. It can also be downloaded via https://github.com/moodleuulm/moodle-local_profilecohort

Disclaimer - I wrote this plugin (on behalf of Ulm University).

Comment: Sorry for the delay - thank you!! This is fantastic